# A function of a matrix is a projection operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projection-matrices

> Let $P_1, P_2, \cdots, P_k$ be projection operators satisfying $\sum_{i=1}^{k} P_i = I$.
> The function $\Phi(X)$ is defined as follows:
> $$ \Phi(X) = \sum_{i=1}^{k} P_i X P_i$$
> Show that $\Phi^2 = \Phi$.

**My try**: It can be shown that $P_iPj=0, i\neq j$, which gives:
$$\Phi^2(X) = \sum_{i,j}P_i X P_iP_j X P_j = \sum_{i}P_i X P_i X P_i$$
I have no idea on how to proceed further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computation of $\Phi^2(X)$ seems to be incorrect; informally, it shouldn't involve more than one $X$.

We should have

$$\Phi^2(X) = \Phi\left(\sum_{i = 1}^k P_i X P_i\right) = \sum_{j = 1}^k P_j \left(\sum_{i = 1}^k P_i X P_i\right) P_j .$$
Rearranging the sums and applying the definition of projection operator, together with the fact that you mentioned (that $P_i P_j = 0$ for $i \neq j$), yields the identity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is $\Phi(X)$ a projection operator?

Comment: What happens when you carry out the steps I outlined in my answer?

Comment: It will give $\Phi^2=\Phi$, but the $X$ in the middle confuses me!